# symfony 4 string instead of UploadedFile in form collection entity with file type create

Tags: file-upload, symfony4

I have the following error: "*Argument 1 passed to App\Service\FileUploader::upload() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile, string given*"

I applied the solution found in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50233669/symfony-4-form-collection-entity-with-file-type-create) but it did not change anything. Quite normal, it's not excactly the same error. Can anyone help me please ?

My goal here is to attach multiple documents to a company from the company screen.

I have been trying to solve the problem since yesterday morning. Now, it's time for me to make a break away from keyboard for 1 or 2 hours ...

Here is the code:

**Document entity**

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\DocumentRepository")
 */
class Document
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $fichier;

    /**
     * @var UploadedFile
     */
    private $file;

    // ...
}
```

**Entreprise entity**

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\EntrepriseRepository")
 */
class Entreprise
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Document", mappedBy="entreprise", orphanRemoval=true, cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $documents;

    // ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->documents = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...

    public function getDocuments()
    {
        return $this->documents;
    }

    public function addDocument(Document $document)
    {
        if (!$this->documents->contains($document)) {
            $this->documents[] = $document;
            //...
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeDocument(Document $document)
    {
        if ($this->documents->contains($document)) {
            $this->documents->removeElement($document);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

**Entreprise Form Type**namespace App\Form\Type;

```
use App\Entity\Entreprise;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

class EntrepriseType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('documents', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => DocumentType::class,
                'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
                'allow_add' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                ])
            // ...
            ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Entreprise::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Entreprise Controller**

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileException;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use App\Entity\Entreprise;
use App\Form\Type\EntrepriseType;
use App\Repository\EntrepriseRepository;
use App\Service\FileUploader;

class EntrepriseController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/entreprise/{id}", name="entreprise_detail")
     * @Route("/entreprise/new", name="entreprise_new")
     */
    public function index(Entreprise $entreprise = null, Request $request, ObjectManager $manager, FileUploader $fileUploader)
    {
        if (!$entreprise) {
            $entreprise = new Entreprise();
        }

        $formDetail = $this->createForm(EntrepriseType::class, $entreprise);
        $formDetail->handleRequest($request);

        if ($formDetail->isSubmitted() && $formDetail->isValid()) {
            $this->setDefault($entreprise);

            // Téléchargement des nouveaux documents rattachés à l'entreprise
            $documents = $entreprise->getDocuments();
            foreach ($documents as $document) {
                if (!$document->getId()){
                    /** @var Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile $file */
                    $file = $document->getFile();

                    $document->setFichier($fileUploader->upload($file));
                }
            }

            // Mise à jour de la base de données
            $manager->persist($entreprise);
            $manager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('entreprise_detail', ['id'=> $entreprise->getId()]);
        }

        return $this->render('entreprise/index.html.twig', [
            'formDetail' => $formDetail->createView(),
            'entreprise' => $entreprise,
        ]);
    }
    // ...
}
```

PS : Sorry if my english is not good enough but if you want, you can answer in french.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and solved it by removing the type casting in the getFile() and setFile() in the entity. I suppose this is located in your Document entity.

Look for:

```
public function getFile(): ?string
{
    return $this->file;
}

public function setFile(string $file): self
{
    $this->file = $file;

    return $this;
}
```

and replace it with

```
public function getFile()
{
    return $this->file;
}

public function setFile($file): self
{
    $this->file = $file;

    return $this;
}
```

This will make sure that the file property will have an Instance of the UploadedFile class instead of invoking the __toString method of the same class (due to casting of type to string).